# PHP xpath how to get start tag

Tags: php, html, forms, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to fetch a form start tag with attributes from a DomDocument loaded with a HTML string.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//form[@class="af-form acf-form"]');

if ($result->length > 0) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(($result->item(0)->C14N()));
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
}
```

But this way it prints out the entire form. I would like to fetch only this bit:

```
<form action="http://localhost/wp-test/form-loose" class="af-form acf-form" id="form_5b72d1cd12cc0" method="POST">
```

How to do so?

Comment: What is inside `$result`?

Comment: DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 1
)

Comment: I think with xpath you can't do that, you can extract just the whole elements. However after you extract the `form` you can then manipulate that in php with regex (preg_match) or sub string to get whatever you need

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I was thinking the same (but was hoping for a solution in xpath.) Another solution would be to extract the attributes and build the form tag html string manually.

Comment: By using firebug (Firefox), or Web Developer Toolbar(Firefox) to open up the page you want to get data from. Right click on the value you want to get and then click `inspect`. On the bottom of the nodelist you'll see  an xpath that you can click, you can copy it and use it in your DomDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath fetches nodes, not opening/closing tags. DOM is an hierarchy of objects - only the serialized (HTML) string has the opening/closing tags.

However, here are two possible approaches:

Clone the node without its child nodes. Save the clone and remove the closing tag with a string function.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<form 
  action="http://localhost/wp-test/form-loose" 
  class="af-form acf-form" id="form_5b72d1cd12cc0" method="POST">
some other stuff
<input>
</form>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$result = $xpath->evaluate('//form[@class="af-form acf-form"][1]');
foreach ($result as $node) {
  echo substr($document->saveHTML($node->cloneNode()), 0, -7);
}
```

Output:

```
<form action="http://localhost/wp-test/form-loose" class="af-form acf-form" id="form_5b72d1cd12cc0" method="POST">
```

Or you save each attribute:

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate('//form[@class="af-form acf-form"][1]');
foreach ($result as $node) {
    $result = '<'.$node->nodeName;
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
        $result .= $document->saveHTML($attribute);
    }
    $result .= '>';
    echo $result;
}
```

Note: Adding `[1]` to the Xpath expression limits the result list to the first found node.